# Spring MVC @RequestBody does not work for JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and when I try pass JSONObject with @RequestBody annotation in controller, I see this error :

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported]
```

I am curious about one thing. When I am try this in Spring Boot, It is working well. What is the difference between Spring MVC's and Spring Boot's @RequestBody annotation for JSONObject ?

Also, when I change to "@RequestBody String str", It is working fine on Spring MVC.

My issue is, why @RequestBody annotation works fine with Spring Boot but does not work Spring MVC with JSONObject [ with same code ].

My data(from postman), code and maven dependencies are below.

> {
> "oid": "oid",
> "name":"name",
> "surname":"surname"
> }

```
@PostMapping(value = "/somepath")
public JSONObject methodName(@RequestBody JSONObject params) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put("username", "responseUserName");
    jsonObject.put("email", "responseEmail");
    jsonObject.put("password", "asdfasf");

    return jsonObject;
}
```

> <spring.version>5.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: *why @RequestBody annotation works fine with Spring Boot but does not work Spring MVC*: Almost certainly because you're missing a dependency that the Boot structure includes.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- which dependency do I miss? May you help me please ?